# Where does the whatsapp store its image for default wallpaper?

Tags: image, resources, whatsapp

I had set wallpaper in WhatsApp. Now the original photo had been deleted but it's still there in wallpaper. Can anyone tell where does whatsapp app store its image resource for its wallpaper? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have found the file used by WhatsApp to store wallpaper, that is ***wallpaper.bkup***, and that can be opened with any Image Opener.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneStorage/Whatsapp/Themes/downloads/yourphotoname.jpg. 
In my case where I use Gbwhatsapp its stored here I don't know for whatsapp but I think it probably would be same check it!

Comment: Sorry for delay! But there is no such folder, but one thing I found is that wallpaper.bkup file. But there is no article for opening it!

Answer (score 0):

With rooted phone search in

```
#root:/data/data/com.whatsapp/files/Wallpapers/...
```

Note: `...` is the encryption numbers of wallpaper used, you can open it with explore as image option.